# How do i connect my app to firebase function and have nodemailer email me my contact form?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, nodemailer

I trying to connect my firebase cloud function to my ionic app and have my contact form information sent to me via email. Im using firebase and nodemailer. I'm currently able to push the contact form to my firebase database. But I don't know how to connect the 2 together. I'm still new to all of this thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/email-confirmation https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cloud firestore trigger , once the data has been created , do node mailer function , I'm on my phone but Google "cloud functions triggers "